# Does Core Data store any state related information outside of the SQLite file

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

When using an SQLite persistent data store does Core Data have any kind of cache/files outside of what is stored within the sqlite file?

I was having a weird crash when calling deleteObject on the ManagedObjectContext, and using SQLiteStudio to examine the pure db records out of the sqlite file from the app bundle didn't show anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: I believe Scott's answer to be correct. I can't find any other files within the bundle or within the simulators file system directories that relate anything to core data. The crash was due to an object being loaded via a one-to-many relationship, i had some code attached to the awakeFromFetch method on the child object that was being run at the same time as trying to delete the child object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Mac OS X 10.7 and iOS 5, there are options to store binary fields as external files. However, if this is not enabled for any of the fields in your model, then everything should be stored in the persistent store file.